# When we use new keyword for create new DateTime (object)

Tags: c#

What is the different between this

```
DateTime thisTime = new DateTime();
```

and this

```
DateTime thisTime;
```

Who is the better performance, and who is the better practice for used. For beginning when is create is have the same date times. I used *thisTime* to add dateTime from file who has 8000 rows, with method *ParseExact()*.

Comment: we use new keyword when creating an instance of a type.For value types this is not mandatory, but for reference types. `ParseExact` needs an out parameter,so the usage is like you have an input and you want an `DateTime` output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I’m going to explain this with a different type first, you’ll see why later.

```
string myString;
```

This is a variable *declaration*. It allocates some space in the memory to be able to hold `string` objects. It does not however fill that space with any content. So the variable contains `null` which essentially means that there is no object.

```
myString = "foo";
```

This is a variable *assignment*. It fills the memory allocated before with some value. That value is *a reference* to the string object which contains `"foo"`. That means that the memory location that was prepared for the variable does not contain the string itself, but just a note where else to find it.

```
string myString = "foo";
```

This combines both above and *initializes* the declared variable directly.

---

Now, for `DateTime` this is a bit different. `DateTime` is a value type, that means that variables of that type do not only store a reference but instead the actual content of the object. Another simple type is an `int` where the variable just stores the integer value directly.

Since variables of value types contain the value directly, they are not references, and as such they cannot be `null`. Instead, declared variables of value types will be automatically initialized with the *default value* for that type.

In general, this is achieved by using `default(TypeName)`, e.g. `default(DateTime)` (this also works for reference types, e.g. `default(string)` which returns `null`). And for value types, `default(DateTime)` happens to be the same as `new DateTime()`.

However, the C# compiler will usually enforce you to *explicitely* initialize variables before you use them. So even when technically, the memory would be prefilled with the default value, the compiler will complain, if you don’t explicitely set a value.

So if you want to use `thisTime`, you will have to assign a value to it. But you do not have to assign the default value to it, if you plan to assign a completely different value anyway. So if you e.g. plan to use `ParseExact` later to get a DateTime, then just leave the variable uninitialized until you assign it.

E.g.

```
// do this
DateTime thisTime;
thisTime = DateTime.ParseExact(…);

// but not this
DateTime thisTime = new DateTime(); // or default(DateTime)
thisTime = DateTime.ParseExact(…);
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference they both return the default value of DateTime in C# which is 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM and performance wise they are both the same. I would recommend the second option as it uses less code.

In C# DateTime is a struct not a class therefore it can't be null and will always default to 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM regardless of how you declare it.

The different ways are: `DateTime thisTime;`, `DateTime thisTime = new DateTime();` and `DateTime thisTime = default(DateTime);`

Also instead of using `ParseExact` I would recommend using `TryParseExact` so the code doesn't throw an exception if the string doesn't match the format.

```
DateTime thisTime;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact("Inputted Date", "Date Format", 
                System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                DateTimeStyles.None, out thisTime))
{
    //success code
}
else
{
    //failure code
}
```